# How to get the element that fired the "onclick" event without passing event argument?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can i get the DOM element which fired onclick, in this situation :

```
<div onclick="ajax('?section=panel');">Hi</div>
```

and the ajax function is :

```
function ajax(url)
{
 alert(caller_element.innerHTML); // I need `caller_element` contain a reference to that DIV
 ...xmlhttp(url)...
}
```

**Note that i cannot change HTML, i can only change `ajax()` function.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Function.prototype.call` to set the context of a function, like so:

```
<div onclick="ajax.call(this, '?section=panel');">Hi</div>
```

```
function ajax(url) {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    ...xmlhttp(url)...
}
```

It would be just as easy to pass it as an argument, though.

Comment: the problem is i cannot change HTML i can only change `ajax(...)` function. is it possible in my situation?

Comment: i think the only way that it dont need to change much of my codes is to use prototype.call, i must call our HTMLer to change his codes :). Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this HTML code:

```
<div onclick="ajax(this, '?section=panel');">Hi</div>
```

and JS:

```
function ajax(caller_element, url)
{
 alert(caller_element.innerHTML);
 ...xmlhttp(url)...
}
```

Comment: the problem is i cannot change HTML i can only change `ajax(...)` function. is it possible in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible without modifying the HTML. If your situation permits, you could use the `id` tag...

```
<div id="whatever" onclick="ajax('?section-panel');">Hi</div>
```

---

```
function ajax(url) {
    alert(document.body.getElementById("whatever").innerHTML);
    ...xmlhttp(url)...
}
```

Comment: Can't he just use Function.prototype.call to set the context of a function, like in the anwsers?

Comment: @Jitamaro Yes if he can modify the HTML, no if he can't. Either way, I was just offering another alternative. :)